# Rails, How to hide/show button, if multiple textbox are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
<%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price],class: "form-control pricee",id: "price",:maxlength => 4,:required => true %>
<%= text_field_tag :mobile, params[:mobile],class: "form-control mobilee",id: "mobile",:maxlength => 10,:required => true %>
<%= submit_tag "add", class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary form_submit" %>
```

I am getting problem hide/show button, if text fields are empty. I am little bit confused to about use tow id's of text fields in js.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery it should be (if you want to make it work while typing):

```
$('[type="text"]').keypress(function(){
    if( $('[name="textbox1"]').val() || $('[name="textbox2"]').val() )
        $('[name="buttonExecute"]').show()
    else
        $('[name="buttonExecute"]').hide()
})
```

Note that button is hiding "IF TWO TEXTS ARE EMPTY". Also I think you should change a button to:

```
<button id="buttonExecute" type="button">Execute</button>
```

.. or something like this.

Comment: it's working as in normal html code, and sorry for this, i want execute in rails.